# Can't add value to the new column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added a new column to my table. I did it in two ways: using SSMS's UI and with code:

```
alter table People add newColumn bit
```

I can see it, it is all fine.
And now I can't add values to this column. I try to do it in SSMS in window 'Edit first 200 rows' and with code

```
insert into dbo.People (peopleINN, newColumn) 
VALUES ('1111111111',    -- it insert this
        1);              -- but don't insert this, is is null
```

I can't insert values to the new column.

Comment: Any triggers on the table ?

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool sending SQL commands to the database server. What's the *actual* problem? What is the actual table schema, real commands and actual result you got back? Are there any triggers that fail and roll back? If I create a table with a `bit` column, INSERT will work just fine

Comment: Post an example that can actually reproduce your problem - a CREATE TABLE, INSERT, SELECT and the results.

Comment: @VBoka Thank's, it is all triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the alter and insert process at one time at once there will definitely be an error. But this can be solved if you use the "GO" command between alter and insert

```
alter table People add newColumn bit
GO
insert into dbo.People (peopleINN, newColumn) 
VALUES ('1111111111',    -- it insert this
        1);
```

If alter and insert are in the begin-end, use EXEC ('insert into').

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='product' AND COLUMN_NAME='A')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE product ADD A varchar(20) default NULL
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] VALUES (200,200,100,''test'')')
END
```

Comment: You answer would explain an *error* on the insert.  But it doesn't explain `NULL` values.  You may be correct that the OP is really getting an error and just calling that "NULL", but that is not how the question is phrased.